# JS get DOM element within a Class, that was created by the Class?

Tags: javascript

I have a JS Class that generates some content then I have some event listeners listening to the newly-created content, right now it looks like that:

https://jsfiddle.net/2fa6k4jz/

```
const articles = [{ text: "abc" },{ text: "xyz" }]

class Page {
 constructor(articles) {
    this.articles = articles;
  };
  
  render() {
    this.articles.forEach((article) => {
        const art = document.createElement("article");
        art.textContent = article.text;
      
        document.body.appendChild(art);
    })
  }
}

const blog = new Page(articles);
blog.render();

document.querySelectorAll("article").forEach((article) => {
   article.addEventListener("click", (e) => alert(e.target.textContent));
});
```

Is there a way to move my eventListener logic to the inside of the Class? I have tried moving `const articles = document.querySelectorAll("article")` to `constructor` but it returs null as the articles aren't already there...

Thanks for any hints!

Comment: Just an idea: you could use custom elements and attach the event listener on the connectedCallback(): https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components/Using_custom_elements

Comment: Bind the event when you create it... `const art = document.createElement("article"); art.addEventListener('click', ....`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes u can do move ur event listener logic to the inside class by adding ur addEventListner method to the class Page.
try this :

```
const articles = [{ text: "abc" }, { text: "xyz" }];

class Page {
  constructor(articles) {
    this.articles = articles;
  }

  render() {
    this.articles.forEach((article) => {
      const art = document.createElement("article");
      art.textContent = article.text;

      document.body.appendChild(art);
    });
  }

  addEventListenerToArticles() {
    document.querySelectorAll("article").forEach((article) => {
      article.addEventListener("click", (e) => alert(e.target.textContent));
    });
  }
}

const blog = new Page(articles);
blog.render();
blog.addEventListenerToArticles();
```

Comment: Deleted my post because @tarik mardy beat me to the punch - good suggestion!

Comment: No problem! Thank u for ur time and consideration of my suggestion @Ryan.

Answer (score 1):

You can attach the eventListener inside your render function

```
{ text: "abc" },
{ text: "xyz" }
]

class Page {
 constructor(articles) {
    this.articles = articles;
  };
  
  render() {
    this.articles.forEach((article) => {
        const art = document.createElement("article");
      art.textContent = article.text;
      art.addEventListener("click", (e) => alert(e.target.textContent));
      document.body.appendChild(art);
    })
  }
}

const blog = new Page(articles);
blog.render();
```